# Create a list from interface information

Tags: java, list, jsp, servlets, interface

I have the following code:

```
    List lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
    String ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //elegimos a qué pantalla pasar en función de la acción que nos llegue de la interfaz

    //ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");    
    //action = request.getParameter("action");
    if ("Buscar todas las recetas".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getAllReceipes());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else if ("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getSomeReceipes(ingrediente));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else if ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        do {
            ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");    
            action = request.getParameter("action");
            lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
        } while ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action));
    }
```

What I want to do from it is to get an ingredients from the interface and save it on a list. The problem is that everytime I save the same ingredient in the list.

**This is what I would like to do:**

- User write: `Tomato`
- List information: `Tomato`
- User press: `agregar ingrediente` (add ingredient)
- User write: `Salt`
- List information: `Tomato, Salt`
- User press: `agregar ingrediente` (add ingredient)
- User write: `Butter`
- List information: `Tomato, Salt, Butter`
- User press: `agregar ingrediente` (add ingredient)
- User write: `Lettuce`
- List information: `Tomato, Salt, Butter, Lettuce`
- User press: `buscar por ingredientes`

**This is what I have:**

- User write: `Tomato`
- List information: `Tomato`
- User press: `agregar ingrediente` (add ingredient)

After the first time, I get a never ending loop with a list of `Tomato,Tomato,Tomato,Tomato...`

Any ideas of how can I do that?

This is the correct code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    List lIngredients = (List) session.getAttribute("Ingredientes");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    if (lIngredients == null) {
       lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
       session.setAttribute("Ingredientes", lIngredients);
    }
    String ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //elegimos a qué pantalla pasar en función de la acción que nos llegue de la interfaz

    if ("Buscar todas las recetas".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getAllReceipes());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
              lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
              request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getSomeReceipes(lIngredients));
              request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
             lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
             request.getRequestDispatcher("option.jsp").forward(request, response);
             ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
             action = request.getParameter("action");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a web application.

A web application works by accepting data from the user, and displaying some sort of result (which may include a new form). *And then it ends*. The servlet is over, there is nothing more to do. You can't get any more information from the user except what was in the request already.

So how do you interact with the user, building up something over several inputs? You certainly can't do that in a loop like you do in a console program.

What you do is keep the data you already got somewhere permanent. For example, in the session. And you display the form for the next input using a JSP. And then your servlet ends.

But the user gets that form on his browser. If he decides to continue working, he will send you the form filled with the new information. He calls your servlet again. Your servlet has to get back the data it saved in the session, and continue as if it was in the next iteration of a loop.

How does your servlet know which iteration of the loop it is in? Well, if there is no saved session data, then it's the start of the interaction. If there is saved data, there should be enough data to go on. For example, if you saved the content of your list in the session, then next time your servlet is called, you'll check first if you have a list. If so, then you will add to it. If not, you'll create a new list and save it in the session.

Bottom line: no loops that expect user input.

Now, this is what you have right now:

```
do {
        ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");    
        action = request.getParameter("action");
        lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
} while ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action));
```

You add the information to the new list that you created. But you have an endless loop, because `action` is never going to change in the current run of the servlet. As it is not going to change, this is an endless loop.

You have to check first if there is a list saved in your session, and if so, just add to it. If not, create one. But you only add one item to it, and then you have to display the form again and finish.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!.. There is just something, when you say "What you do is keep the data you already got somewhere permanent. For example, in the session. And you display the form for the next input using a JSP. And then your servlet ends.

But the user gets that form on his browser. If he decides to continue working, he will send you the form filled with the new information." how can I do so? calling the same jsp all the time? Big thank you

Comment: Yes, in most cases, you'll need to redirect to the same JSP which displays the form again. Perhaps you'll want to display the content of the list as well in that JSP, so it will not be *exactly* the same.

Comment: So after this lines should I do something like                                                           ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");    
            action = request.getParameter("action");
            lIngredients.add(ingrediente);                                                            request.getRequestDispatcher("options.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: I think so, though perhaps this should be done only if `action` is `Agregar ingrediente`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I post the correct code :)